# Run .py script via sh import module error

Tags: python, c++, xcode, sh

This is a very basic question on how to code in python and run your script from a very beginner. 
I'm writing a script using Xcode9.4.1 which is supposed to be for python3.6. I then have an sh script run.sh, in the same folder of the script (say "my_folder") which simply looks like

```
python my_script.py
```

The python script looks like

```
from tick.base import TimeFunction
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

v = np.arange(0., 10., 1.)
f_v = v + 1
u = TimeFunction((v, f_v))
plt.plot(v, u.value(v))
print('donne!\n')
```

But as I try to run my_script.sh from the terminal I get a "ImportError: No module named tick.base" error. 
But the tick folder is actually present in "my_computer/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages" and up to last week I was using Spyder from anaconda navigator and everything was correctly working, so no "import error" occurred.

The question is quite trivial, in some sense it simply is "what's the typical procedure to code and run python script and how modules are supposed to be imported-downloaded when running on a given machine?"

I need it since my script is to be run on another machine through ssh and using my laptop to make some attempts. Up to last year I used to work in C and only need to move some folders with code and .h files.

Thank for help!

EDIT 1:
From the Spyder 3.2.7 setting, where the script was giving non problem, I printed the

```
import sys
print(sys.path)
```

The -manually- copied the content to the sys.path variable in my_script.py and rerun 'run.sh' and now getting a new (strange) error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
[...]
 File "/Users/my_computer/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tick/array/build/array.py", line 106
def tick_double_array_to_file(_file: 'std::string', array: 'ArrayDouble const &') -> "void":
                                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 1):

First, check the python which you are calling the script with is pointing to the anaconda python and it is of the same version you are expecting it to be. You can do "which python" command in Linux and Mac to which the path which points to python. It if is pointing to some different version or build of python than the one which you are expecting then add the needed path to the system environment PATH variable. In Linux and Mac this can be done by adding the following line in the .bashrc file at the /home/ folder:

```
export PATH=/your/python/path:$PATH
```

And then source the .bashrc file.
    source .bashrc

If you are on a operating system like cent os ,breaking the default python path can break your yum so be careful before changing it.

Comment: under "which python" I get "/anaconda/bin/python" instead of "anaconda3/lib/python3.6" that I would like.... But is there a way ti "momentarily" change the path? Or to state it explicitly at the beginning of the my_script.sh file?

Comment: if you want to run only once, you can run: 
/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/python my_script.py

Comment: I get a "no such file or directory". However under "ls /anaconda3/lib/python3.6" it lists the right files

Answer (score 0):

I am running a script in PyCharm and under the Project Interpretor I have the path 
C:\envs\conda\keras2\python.exe

When I try to run the script via ssh on the server I get a 'no module named' error. I get 
/usr/bin/python as the ans to 'which python' on the server itself. Could you tell me which path I must add for the script to run properly?

Comment: I'm sorry, but you're answering another question or I'm not understanding your point..?